# Android app making(is it possible to exploit github page?)

Tags: android, database, github

I am making a simple android application. To describe it, It shows a list of CPU models, like i7, i5, and AMD processor, so on.

I am not familiar with using a database! So I want to write txt file and store it on my GitHub homepage. Then, is it possible that load the txt file and show it in an android application?

Comment: are you create file txt and share to GitHub or get the file from GitHub and read the file(show in text view)???

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying!

Comment: Because I think it can save some money for making server

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
You have to create a `public repository` and inside this repository store your text file as `JSON File`. [see this](https://gitlab.com/jakir123/personaldictionary/-/blob/master/app_info.json)

**Note:** repository must be public

and then you can access this as `API URL` using any `httpclient` like below.

```
val client = OkHttpClient() // have to add OkHttpClient in gradle file.
val request = Request.Builder()
   .url("https://gitlab.com/jakir123/personaldictionary/-/raw/master/app_info.json") // the file link don't forget to replace blob with raw.
   .build()

client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
   override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
          EasyLog.logE(
               "Exception in getting app info: ${e.localizedMessage}",
                    "AppInfoRepository"
          )
   }

   override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val body = response.body()?.string()
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val appInfo = gson.fromJson(body, AppInfo::class.java)

            // here you can access value like below
            val versionCode = appInfo.version_code
            val versionName = appInfo.version_name
   }
})
```

AppInfo model class

```
data class AppInfo(
    val version_code: Int,
    val version_name: String,
    val developer_name: String,
    val developer_email: String,
    val developer_image: String,
    val playstore_link: String
)
```

**Update: Java Example Code**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
// GET request
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("your_url")
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
         // handle on failure here.
       }

       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException  {
              if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                   throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
              } else {
                  // do something wih the response
                  String result = response.body().toString() // you will get your json text here as string.
                  Gson gson = new Gson(); // this library should be added in gradle
                  AppInfo appInfo= gson.fromJson(result, AppInfo.class);
                  // here you can access value like below
                  int versionCode = appInfo.version_code
                  String versionName = appInfo.version_name
              } 
             
       }
});
```

AppInfo model class

```
public class AppInfo{

    private int version_code;
    private String version_name;
    private String developer_name;
    private String developer_email;
    private String developer_image;
    private String playstore_link;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Oh, you are so kind! Thank you Hossain. I think it is Kotlin, right? I will try it.

Comment: @Jaker Hossain  I am so glad for your help.... Is it possible that you can rewrite the code in Java language?